# jQuery wrap failing on IE8, fine on Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a jQuery statement which worked fine on IE7 and works on FF, but is failing on IE8.

The line is:

```
ScratchIFrame().find("fullwordmatch").wrap("<nonmarkupmatch></nonmarkupmatch>");
```

I added the following before it:

```
alert(ScratchIFrame().find("fullwordmatch").length);
alert(ScratchIFrame().html());
```

and get the results:

```
1
<fullwordmatch>test</fullwordmatch>
```

the error occurring is:

```
Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 12
Char: 2305
Code: 0
URI: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
```

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to the doctype you're using or the fact you're using custom html elements.
Try changing the element to;

```
<div id="fullwordmatch">test</div>
```

and searching for it using;

```
ScratchIFrame().find("div#fullwordmatch");
```

Does the error still occur?

Comment: Thanks, seems to have moved on but still having problems.

The wrap started working, but we then get other problems (like destroying markers afterwards - previously destroyed all </fullwordmatch> but obviously can't do that with </div>).

It looks like the IE8 scripting engine messes about with the DOM in ways in which it wasn't asked to. I'm going to investigate more.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue myself.  The cause in my scenario was that I was adding an input element but assigned a .text() to the input tag.  When appending the input tag, it failed generating the same error as you have encountered.